# why this code shows two results in the alert field while i have one output?

Tags: javascript

This is part of my code and i want to know why it shows me two alerts?

```js
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
  case 0:
    {
      alert("sunday");
    }
  case 1:
    {
      alert("monday");
      break;
    }
  case 2:
    {
      alert("tueseday");
      break;
    }
  case 3:
    {
      alert("wednesday");
      break;
    }
  case 4:
    {
      alert("thursday");
      break;
    }
  case 5:
    {
      alert("friday");
      break;
    }
  case 6:
    {
      alert("saturday");
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a break after case 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is break statement missing in the first case.
For case 0, what you have is -

```
case 0 : 
{
   alert("sunday");
}
```

Add a break statement and change it to -

```
case 0 :
{
   alert("sunday");
   break;
}
```